# Unable to pass result to router after calling Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I encounter an error using Meteor. I call an Method.method.

```
Template.WelcomeTemplate.events({

'click #btn-findgame': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked find game button');

    Meteor.call('allocateGame', function(error, id) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error.reason);
        } if (id) {
            Router.go('gameRoom', {_id: id})
        }
    })
}
```

})

With my Method, I check if there is an room available, create one when the isn't otherwise join. And return the ID of this room.

```
Meteor.methods({
allocateGame: function () {
    console.log('allocateGame method called')

    var user = Meteor.user();

    // find game where one player is in the room
    var gameWaiting = Games.findOne({players: {$size: 1}})

    if (!gameWaiting) {
        console.log('no game available, create a new one');
        var newGameId = Games.insert({players: [user._id], active: false, finished: false});
        GameDetails.insert({gameId: newGameId, gameData: []});
        return newGameId
    } else {
        if (_.contains(gameWaiting.players, user._id)) {
            console.log('Cannot play against yourself sir')
        } else {
            console.log('Joining game');
            Games.update({_id: gameWaiting._id}, {
                $set: {active: true},
                $push: {players: user._id}
            });
            return gameWaiting._id;
        }
    };
}
})
```

And my Router:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('welcome', {
        path: '/',
        controller: WelcomeController})

    this.route('gameRoom', {
        path: '/game/_:id'
    })
});
```

The Error I recieve is:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'allocateGame': TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of null
    at Object.IronLocation.set (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:1293:12)
```

And indeed, If I don't return an ID the Routing will continue as normal. However when I return an ID in my WelcomeTemplate an error will occur.

EDIT:

Even thought my MongoDB is updating my MiniMongo DB is empty. There must be a problem with syncing. Any idea where to look?

Answer (score 1):

In the route, you set the path to be `'/game/_:id'`, that is, a parameter with the name `id`. In your call to `Router.go`, you pass a parameter with the name `_id`.

Don't know if this solves your problem, but it's an error.

Comment: Note: the path should probably be `'/game/:_id'`.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem, it's some magic Iron Router will handle.  It look's like my miniMongo datbase is not syncing.

Comment: Thanks Hubert OG. I overlooked your answer, it was indeed '/game/:_id' instead of '/game/_:id' 

I almost rewrote the whole app before I found this out :D

Answer (score 1):

This kind of embarrassing taking in account how many hours I've spent on fixing this. The error was created because of an error in my routers.js

```
 this.route('gameRoom', {
        path: '/game/_:id'
    })
```

Should be:

```
this.route('gameRoom', {
        path: '/game/:_id'
    })
```

Happy coding.